# How to overcome "Variable returned by scilab argument function is incorrect" while using fsolve in scilab?

Tags: scilab

While solving one problem in the fluid mechanics topic, I came across a situation where I have to solve 4 non linear equation to get 4 unknown variable values. So, I used fsolve function in scilab to solve the equations. My code is as follows:

```
clc
clear

function f=F(x)
f(1)=x(1)-(0.4458*x(2)^(-2))
f(2)=x(3)-(0.26936*x(2)*(-1)) 
f(3)=(2.616*x(2))-(x(4)*x(1)^2)
f(4)=(0.316/(x(3)^(1/4)))
endfunction
function j=jacob(x)
 j(1,1)=1;j(1,2)=0.8916*x(2)^(-3);j(1,3)=0;j(1,4)=0
 j(2,1)=0;j(2,2)=0.26936*x(2)^(-2);j(2,3)=1;j(2,4)=0;
 j(3,1)=-2*x(1)*x(4);j(3,2)=2.616;j(3,3)=0;j(3,4)=-1*x(1)^2;
 j(4,1)=0;j(4,2)=0;j(4,3)=-2/x(3)/log(10);j(4,4)=(-0.5*x(4)^(-1.5))-(1/x(4)/log(10));
endfunction
x0=[1 1 2000 1];
[x,v,info]=fsolve(x0,F,jacob);
disp(x);
```

*Error:*

[x,v,info]=fsolve(x0,F,jacob);
                              !--error 98 
Variable returned by scilab argument function is incorrect.
at line      17 of exec file called by :
exec('D:\Desktop files\Ajith\TBC\SCILAB code\Chapter_08\fsolve.sce', -1)

**Details of the question:-**

*Actual question:* Heated air at 1 atm and 35 degree C is to be transported in a 150m long circular plastic duct at a rate of 0.35 m3/s. If the head loss in the pipe is not to exceed 20m, determine the minimum diameter of the duct?

*Book name:* Fluid Mechanics: Fundamentals and Applications by Y.A.Cengel and J.M.Cimbala.

*Page and question number:* Page no.: 345, EXAMPLE 8-4

*ISBN of the book:* 0-07-247236-7

*Textbook link:*  https://www.academia.edu/32439502/Cengel_fluid_mechanics_6_edition.PDF

In my code: x(1) is velocity, x(2) is the diameter, x(3) is the Reynolds number, x(4) is the friction factor

Expected answers: x(1)=6.24, x(2)=0.267, x(3)=100800, x(4)=0.0180.

My thoughts about the error:

1. What is see is that if I change the power of the variable such as from 0.5 to 2 or -1.5 to 1, answer is calculated and displayed. So, the problem is somewhere around the power of the variables used.
2. Also the initial values of the x, I saw that for some initial value there is no error and I got the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the description of the problem in the book, there is only one non-trivial equation (the third) all other give directly other unknowns as functions of `D`. Here is the code to determine the diameter:

```
function out=F(D)
    V = 0.35/%pi/D^2*4;
    Re = V*D/1.655e-5;
    f = 20/(150/D*V^2/2/9.81);
    out = 1/sqrt(f) + 2*log10(2.51/Re/sqrt(f));    
endfunction
D0 = 1;
[D,v,info]=fsolve(D0,F);
disp(D)
```

Comment: Thank you Mottelet sir for sharing your knowledge.I am using SCILAB 5.5.2 version.Once I changed the code by adding the transverse to the code by adding a transpose to the code, I got output without error but I don't get expected output.Code is very sensitive to the initial value, by changing initial value my answer get different sometimes gives the same error mentioned in the question.

And what about the jacob function sir, should that be also a column matrix or not?
Or some times same initial values are displayed as the answer which is actually wrong. Any way thank for your answer sir..!